# Cannot set focus on TextBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I can't set focus on my `TextBox`, I have this code:

```
private void txbUid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Key != Key.Tab) return; // here control doesn't loose focus

  string stringUid = txbUid.Text;
  long uid;

  if (!TryParseUid(stringUid, out uid))
  {
    //string errMsg = $"Niepoprawny kod UID: {stringUid}";
    //lblError.Text = errMsg;
    //this.LogError(errMsg);
    //txbUid.Text = "";
    //txbUid.Focus();
    return; // here control looses focus
  }
}
```

As you can see, I tried commenting out particular lines to see whether on of them is causing the problem. But nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this was caused by pressing tab button.

If it wasn't pressed, control stay focused as it should - and that was misleading.

When I pressed tab, then by default, the *next* control got focus, i.e. I handled the event, but it was passed further to containing control, which set focus on other control. Thus unexpected behaviour.

The solution was to set `e.Handled`, instead of using `Focus()` method (after which further processing of an event set focus to other control anyway), to `true` in the event, so pressing tab event wasn't processed any further.

Example code:

```
private void txbUid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Key != Key.Tab) return; // here control doesn't loose focus

  string stringUid = txbUid.Text;
  long uid;

  if (!TryParseUid(stringUid, out uid))
  {
    // no need to comment out anything
    string errMsg = $"Niepoprawny kod UID: {stringUid}";
    lblError.Text = errMsg;
    this.LogError(errMsg);
    txbUid.Text = "";
    // mark event as handled
    e.Handled = true;
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Tab` character will be handled internally by the `TextBox`. You can try setting `e.Handled = true` before returning. If that doesn't work, you need to handle [PreviewKeyDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.contentelement.previewkeydown?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead (and don't forget to set the `Handled` property).